# How to pass parameters to JQL in python jira?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api

I have the following line here for JQL i want to pass two parameters how can I achieve it ?

issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('status = "Pending QA Deployment" AND project = ALPHA', startAt=0, maxResults=2000, validate_query=True, fields=None, expand=None, json_result=None)

two parameters are status and project. Please let me know how to achieve this ?

Comment: And does this not work in some way?

Comment: this works but not as parameters :(

Comment: It worked ! I did the following 
import sys
projectname = sys.argv[1]
issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('status = "Pending QA Deployment" AND project ='+ projectname , startAt=0, maxResults=2000, validate_query=True, fields=None, expand=None, json_result=None)